# Android layer-list item height not working

Tags: android, android-drawable

I got this drawable, that's just making a little nice border at the bottom.
I made it this way to get some more shiny than just a rectangle border.

The code works for API 24.
On API 23 it doesn't show up.
And below that, the height doesn't work, and it just fills everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:height="3dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really fixed the issue, but found a workaround.

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="3dp"
     android:background="@drawable/borderbottom"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```